# Display List of Products With Missing Attribute?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've searched and searched but have not been able to find an answer to this, so thank you in advance for your help!

I am wanting to display a list (in the Admin portal, on the Products page) of all products that do NOT have a specific attribute assigned (so we can easily find products that need to be updated).

I have the same functionality already set up to display products that are missing other criteria (shipping class, weight, etc.) using a variation of this code and it works great, but I am not sure how to modify it to display products without the pa_sort-chassis attribute... so far, this is what I've got - it doesn't produce any results, though.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'products_no_chassisattribute_admin' );
 
function products_no_chassisattribute_admin(){
    global $pagenow, $typenow;
    if ( 'edit.php' === $pagenow && 'product' === $typenow ) {
      echo '<div class="notice notice-warning is-dismissible"><h3>Products with NO Sort By Chassis Attribute</h3><ul>';
      $args = array(
         'status' => 'publish',
         'visibility' => 'visible',
         'limit' => -1
      );
      $products = wc_get_products( $args );
      foreach ( $products as $product ) {
         if ( ! $product = wc_get_products( array( 'pa_sort-chassis' => '' ) )) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_edit_post_link( $product->get_id() ) ) . '">' . $product->get_name() . '</a></li>';
         }
      }
      echo '</ul></div>';
    }
```